# Link Preview not available

Tags: php, html, seo, metadata

I am developing my personal portfolio . I am facing a problem that is ..
I have placed all the important meta tags in my header.php file and they're visible in the page source code too .. But they are not working . I got to know this when I placed the **Meta OG** to get the link preview on social sites.
Here's the image of my the website from where I am checking the rich link preview

[image]

And here's my website source code image in which you can clearly see the meta tags included

[image]

If something isn't clear from the image then here's the [link](https://www.iamosama.cf/) of my website

**EDIT :** Here's the code of my website's head section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php 

global $baseUrl;
$baseUrl='https://www.iamosama.cf/' ;
?>

    <!-- Basic -->
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Osama - Web Designer and Developer</title>


  <meta name="description" content="Hello , I am Osama . A creative web designer and developer from Karachi , Pakistan" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Web Designer , Web developer , Front end Developer , UI/UX Designer" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Osama - The Web Developer" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>images/favicons/favicon.ico" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Personal Portfolio" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Hello , I am Osama . A creative web designer and developer from Karachi , Pakistan " />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>images/thumb.jpg" />




    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script%7CPoppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>css/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>css/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>css/blogs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>css/ionicons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>css/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseUrl ; ?>css/animate.css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon -->


  <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "Osama",
  "alternateName": "Muhammad Osama",
  "url": "https://www.iamosama.cf/",
  "image": "https://www.iamosama.cf/images/profile.jpg",
  "sameAs": "https://www.iamosama.cf/",
  "jobTitle": "Web Designer and Developer"  
}
</script>

</head>
```

Comment: And you're sure this is not just a bug in the tool you're using? Have you tried any other tool?

Comment: I checked this by uploading link on my facebook profile .. link preview is not available there either

Comment: Nice website. Can you please post the actual source code of your webpage (just until `</head>`)

Comment: Thanks .. I have edited my question and the code of the head section is there